# How to store "%d-%d-%d", year, month, date` as a char?

Tags: c++, string, char, printf, std

How to store variables in a `char` variable?

For example how can the `"date: %d-%d-%d", year, month, date` component of `printf("date: %d-%d-%d", year, month, date)` be stored as a char?

Comment: Do you want to store the formatted string or the format string and parameters separately?

Comment: Formatted string only

Comment: Have you looked at [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)?

Comment: @RSahu Something like this: `const char* s = std::printf("date: %d-%d-%d", year, month, date);`? Apologies if the question seems trivial I am new to C++.

Comment: you can't store a bunch of chars in a single char variable. You need to use a string. Take a look at my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Define a string large enough to hold the formatted output.
2. Use it as the first argument to `sprintf`.

---

```
char output[100];
sprintf(outout, "date: %d-%d-%d", year, month, date);
```

If you are able to use a C++11 compiler, use the safer version of `sprintf`, `snprintf`.

```
char output[100];
snprintf(output, sizeof(output), "date: %d-%d-%d", year, month, date);
```

`snprintf` makes sure that you don't run into buffer overflow errors.

Comment: How can this be extended for strings of unknown length? For example if first and last names are included after the date?

Comment: @Dave, using `std::ostringstream` will be better for such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Use a stringstream as shown below. You can't use a single character to store a bunch of characters because that's what you're trying to do.

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss<<yourdate<<theday<<themonth<<theyear;
std::string mystring = ss.str();
std::cout<<mystring;

//to convert to a C-string
const char* aschar = mystring.c_str();
```

Comment: How to save `mystring` as a `char`?

Comment: Can `ss<<"date: "<<theday<<"-"<<themonth<<"-"<<theyear;` be used to get it into this format: `"date: %d-%d-%d"`?

Comment: yes ss<<"date: "<<theday<<"-"<<themonth<<"-"<<theyear; should work

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).  You can figure out how big a buffer you need by calling `snprintf` with 0 length first then calling it again with an appropriately sized buffer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    const char* pattern = "date: %d-%d-%d";
    int year = 2017;
    int month = 4;
    int date = 27;
    int required = snprintf(nullptr, 0, pattern, year, month, date);
    std::string formatted(required + 1, '\0');
    snprintf(&formatted[0], formatted.size(), pattern, year, month, date);
    // Trim off the extra '\0' character that snprintf puts at the end
    formatted.resize(formatted.size() - 1);

    std::cout << formatted << '\n';
}
```

I've used `std::string` to avoid possible resource leaks, but you could do it with a raw `char*` pointing to a `new`ed array.